# How to set up Facebook app when using applicationIdSuffix in Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-authentication

I am trying to set up the [developers.facebook.com](https://developers.facebook.com/) so my users can sign in with Facebook. I have a question since in my build.grade file I also use the `applicationIdSuffix` as shown below.

[image]

How should I in the picture above enter the package name since I use the `applicationIdSuffix` like this. I mean should I keep the "debug" like `com.toy.android.debug` and what about the Activity like in the picture above `com.toy.android.ui.ActivityMain` , should I add "debug" like com.toy.android.debug.ui.ActivityMain

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled true
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        applicationIdSuffix '.debug'
        versionNameSuffix '-debug'
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
    release {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        applicationIdSuffix '.production'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

    }
}
```

This setup is for debug version, I also can install and run the production version on same device now, that´s very handy but can I create another Facebook app for my "production" version? I guess but must ask right.
what else cavities can I expect with this?